# How to configure a function from `scipy.stats` to work with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, distribution, curve-fitting

I am creating a uniform vector of probabilities, adding weight to a region, converting to probabilities once again.  I want to smooth the curve by fitting a `beta` distribution to the curve.  I can't use `stats.beta.fit` because I don't have any draws from these probabilities only a scaffold for the curve.

**How can I configure a function from `scipy.stats` to work with `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`?** I don't want to limit it to just `beta` distributions if possible. Is there a general way to convert these into a form that can be minimized to optimize the parameter set?

Essentially, I'm looking for the parameter set that best fits the curve to a particular distribution (in this case a `beta`).

Any ideas?

```
# Uniform probabilities
n = 10
x = np.linspace(0,1,n)
probs_num = np.ones(n)/n # y-values

# Update the mass around an area
idx_update = 2
probs_num[idx_update] += 0.382

# Convert fo probs
probs_num = probs_num/probs_num.sum()

# Plot
with plt.style.context("ggplot"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x,probs_num)
    ax.set_ylabel("Density")
    ax.set_xlabel("$x$")


probs_num
```

[image]

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import stats
popt, pcov = curve_fit(stats.beta, x, probs_num) # NOTE: I know this is the wrong way to use it but I'm leaving it as a placeholder
```

In response to the lm answer below:

```
import lmfit
def beta_fcn(x, alpha, beta, loc):
    return stats.beta.pdf(x, alpha, beta, loc)
bmodel = lmfit.Model(beta_fcn)
params = bmodel.make_params(alpha=1, beta=1., loc=0.5)
result = bmodel.fit(probs_num, params, x=x)

# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
# <ipython-input-34-61ec32095934> in <module>()
#       4 bmodel = lmfit.Model(beta_fcn)
#       5 params = bmodel.make_params(alpha=1, beta=1., loc=0.5)
# ----> 6 result = bmodel.fit(probs_num, params, x=x)

# ~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lmfit/model.py in fit(self, data, params, weights, method, iter_cb, scale_covar, verbose, fit_kws, nan_policy, **kwargs)
#     871                              scale_covar=scale_covar, fcn_kws=kwargs,
#     872                              nan_policy=self.nan_policy, **fit_kws)
# --> 873         output.fit(data=data, weights=weights)
#     874         output.components = self.components
#     875         return output

# ~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lmfit/model.py in fit(self, data, params, weights, method, nan_policy, **kwargs)
#    1215         self.userkws.update(kwargs)
#    1216         self.init_fit = self.model.eval(params=self.params, **self.userkws)
# -> 1217         _ret = self.minimize(method=self.method)
#    1218 
#    1219         for attr in dir(_ret):

# ~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py in minimize(self, method, params, **kws)
#    1636                         val.lower().startswith(user_method)):
#    1637                     kwargs['method'] = val
# -> 1638         return function(**kwargs)
#    1639 
#    1640 

# ~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py in leastsq(self, params, **kws)
#    1288         np.seterr(all='ignore')
#    1289 
# -> 1290         lsout = scipy_leastsq(self.__residual, variables, **lskws)
#    1291         _best, _cov, infodict, errmsg, ier = lsout
#    1292         result.aborted = self._abort

# ~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
#     385             maxfev = 200*(n + 1)
#     386         retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
# --> 387                                  gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
#     388     else:
#     389         if col_deriv:

# ~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py in __residual(self, fvars, apply_bounds_transformation)
#     489         if not self._abort:
#     490             return _nan_policy(np.asarray(out).ravel(),
# --> 491                                nan_policy=self.nan_policy)
#     492 
#     493     def __jacobian(self, fvars):

# ~/anaconda/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/lmfit/minimizer.py in _nan_policy(arr, nan_policy, handle_inf)
#    1846 
#    1847         if contains_nan:
# -> 1848             raise ValueError("The input contains nan values")
#    1849     return arr
#    1850 

# ValueError: The input contains nan values
```

Comment: I have an open source Python statistical distibution fitter with a tkinter GUI at https://bitbucket.org/zunzuncode/tkinterstatsdistrofit which allows selection of different scipy.stats continuous distributions for fitting, that might be of some use.

Comment: you probably want `beta.pdf` for the probability distribution function, but may want some other method...  You should also realize that it takes 4 parameters: `a`, `b`, `loc`, and `scale

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `beta.pdf`, as with:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 21
x = np.linspace(0, 1, n)
y = stats.beta.pdf(x, 2.5, 15, 0.3) + np.random.normal(scale=0.1, size=n)

p0 = [2.0, 10.0, 0.5]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(stats.beta.pdf, x, y, p0)
print(popt)
```

You may also find lmfit (https://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) useful.  For this, you would have to wrap `stats.beta.pdf`, but this gives you a lot more flexibility in putting bounds on parameters or fixing them:

```
from lmfit import Model
def beta_fcn(x, alpha, beta, loc):
    return stats.beta.pdf(x, alpha, beta, loc)

bmodel = Model(beta_fcn)

params = bmodel.make_params(alpha=2, beta=10., loc=0.5)
params['alpha'].min = 1.0

result = bmodel.fit(y, params, x=x)

print(result.fit_report())

with plt.style.context("ggplot"):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(x, y, 'o')
    ax.plot(x, result.best_fit)
    ax.set_ylabel("Density")
    ax.set_xlabel("$x$")
plt.show()
```

This will print out

```
[[Model]]
    Model(beta_fcn)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 75
    # data points      = 21
    # variables        = 3
    chi-square         = 0.06244742
    reduced chi-square = 0.00346930
    Akaike info crit   = -116.177008
    Bayesian info crit = -113.043441
[[Variables]]
    alpha:  2.50445306 +/- 0.06843391 (2.73%) (init = 2)
    beta:   14.9105872 +/- 0.31198655 (2.09%) (init = 10)
    loc:    0.29906057 +/- 0.00190835 (0.64%) (init = 0.5)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(alpha, beta) =  0.894
    C(alpha, loc)  = -0.834
    C(beta, loc)   = -0.564
```

(and, to be clear, the best fit values and uncertainties will be the same from the `curve_fit` example above) and a plot of

[image]

Comment: Woah, I'm going to need to unpack this for a bit.  Thanks for the alternative suggestion.  My coworker uses glms for everything but I never really understood when or why he uses them.

Comment: Why the downvote?  I think `stats.beta.pdf` answers the actual question, a worked example was provided, and an alternative suggested.

Comment: @O.rka  I think the main point is: use `stats.beta.pdf`.  Second point: lmfit offers a higher-level interface to curve fitting.  Does 'glms' mean Generalized Linear Model?  That is very different from curve fitting with non-linear least-squares method, as curve_fit() uses.

Comment: Also, I tried your code with my data but got an error regarding `nans` though there were no `nan` values.  I added the details into the question.

Comment: @O.rka  Yeah, the beta function does seem prone to `NaN` and `Inf`.... I'm not sure why that is,  but you may have to play around with bounds on the parameters to prevent that. Hence the lmfit recommendation, which easily allows placing bounds on each named parameter individually.